# Django WritingYourFirstDjangoApp Part5

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I was using the following tutorial website and although I had followed every instruction on the website, this error showed up...

docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial05/

(python shell)

```
In [16]: response = Client.get(reverse('polls:index')) 

Internal Server Error: /polls/ Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/****/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/base.py", line 470, in parse
    compile_func = self.tags[command] KeyError: 'ls'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Users/****/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)   File "/Users/****/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 202, in _get_response
    response = response.render()   File "/Users/****/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content   File "/Users/****/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/response.py", line 81, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)   File "/Users/****/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/response.py", line 63, in resolve_template
    return select_template(template, using=self.using)   File "/Users/****/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/loader.py", line 42, in select_template
    return engine.get_template(template_name)   File "/Users/****/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/backends/django.py", line 34, in get_template
    return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)   File "/Users/****/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/engine.py", line 143, in get_template
    template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)   File "/Users/****u/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/engine.py", line 125, in find_template
    template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)   File "/Users/****/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/loaders/base.py", line 30, in get_template
    contents, origin, origin.template_name, self.engine,   File "/Users/****/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/base.py", line 155, in __init__
    self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()   File "/Users/****/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/base.py", line 193, in compile_nodelist
    return parser.parse()   File "/Users/****/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/base.py", line 472, in parse
    self.invalid_block_tag(token, command, parse_until)   File "/Users/****/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/base.py", line 534, in invalid_block_tag
    "or load this tag?" % (token.lineno, command) django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 1: 'ls'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

--------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last) ~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/base.py in parse(self, parse_until)
    469                 try:
--> 470                     compile_func = self.tags[command]
    471                 except KeyError:

KeyError: 'ls'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TemplateSyntaxError                       Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-16-f2b5e9d8990c> in <module>
----> 1 response = Client.get(reverse('polls:index'))

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/test/client.py in get(self, path, data, follow, secure, **extra)
    730         """Request a response from the server using GET."""
    731         self.extra = extra
--> 732         response = super().get(path, data=data, secure=secure, **extra)
    733         if follow:
    734             response = self._handle_redirects(response, data=data, **extra)

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/test/client.py in get(self, path, data, secure, **extra)
    393         return self.generic('GET', path, secure=secure, **{
    394             'QUERY_STRING': urlencode(data, doseq=True),
--> 395             **extra,
    396         })
    397 

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/test/client.py in generic(self, method, path, data, content_type, secure, **extra)
    468             query_string = parsed[4].encode().decode('iso-8859-1')
    469             r['QUERY_STRING'] = query_string
--> 470         return self.request(**r)
    471 
    472 

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/test/client.py in request(self, **request)
    707             got_request_exception.disconnect(dispatch_uid=exception_uid)
    708         # Check for signaled exceptions.
--> 709         self.check_exception(response)
    710         # Save the client and request that stimulated the response.
    711         response.client = self

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/test/client.py in check_exception(self, response)
    569             self.exc_info = None
    570             if self.raise_request_exception:
--> 571                 raise exc_value
    572 
    573     @property

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner(request)
     45         def inner(request):
     46             try:
---> 47                 response = get_response(request)
     48             except Exception as exc:
     49                 response = response_for_exception(request, exc)

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response(self, request)
    200                 )
    201             try:
--> 202                 response = response.render()
    203             except Exception as e:
    204                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/response.py in render(self)
    103         retval = self
    104         if not self._is_rendered:
--> 105             self.content = self.rendered_content
    106             for post_callback in self._post_render_callbacks:
    107                 newretval = post_callback(retval)

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/response.py in rendered_content(self)
     79         content explicitly using the value of this property.
     80         """
---> 81         template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
     82         context = self.resolve_context(self.context_data)
     83         return template.render(context, self._request)

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/response.py in resolve_template(self, template)
     61         """Accept a template object, path-to-template, or list of paths."""
     62         if isinstance(template, (list, tuple)):
---> 63             return select_template(template, using=self.using)
     64         elif isinstance(template, str):
     65             return get_template(template, using=self.using)

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/loader.py in select_template(template_name_list, using)
     40         for engine in engines:
     41             try:
---> 42                 return engine.get_template(template_name)
     43             except TemplateDoesNotExist as e:
     44                 chain.append(e)

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/backends/django.py in get_template(self, template_name)
     32     def get_template(self, template_name):
     33         try:
---> 34             return Template(self.engine.get_template(template_name), self)
     35         except TemplateDoesNotExist as exc:
     36             reraise(exc, self)

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/engine.py in get_template(self, template_name)
    141         handling template inheritance recursively.
    142         """
--> 143         template, origin = self.find_template(template_name)
    144         if not hasattr(template, 'render'):
    145             # template needs to be compiled

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/engine.py in find_template(self, name, dirs, skip)
    123         for loader in self.template_loaders:
    124             try:
--> 125                 template = loader.get_template(name, skip=skip)
    126                 return template, template.origin
    127             except TemplateDoesNotExist as e:

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/loaders/base.py in get_template(self, template_name, skip)
     28             else:
     29                 return Template(
---> 30                     contents, origin, origin.template_name, self.engine,
     31                 )
     32 

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/base.py in
__init__(self, template_string, origin, name, engine)
    153         self.engine = engine
    154         self.source = str(template_string)  # May be lazy.
--> 155         self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()
    156 
    157     def __iter__(self):

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/base.py in compile_nodelist(self)
    191 
    192         try:
--> 193             return parser.parse()
    194         except Exception as e:
    195             if self.engine.debug:

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/base.py in parse(self, parse_until)
    470                     compile_func = self.tags[command]
    471                 except KeyError:
--> 472                     self.invalid_block_tag(token, command, parse_until)
    473                 # Compile the callback into a node object and add it to
    474                 # the node list.

~/Desktop/Programming1/hello_django/django/django/template/base.py in invalid_block_tag(self, token, command, parse_until)
    532             token,
    533             "Invalid block tag on line %d: '%s'. Did you forget to register "
--> 534             "or load this tag?" % (token.lineno, command)
    535         )
    536 

TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 1: 'ls'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

I have three HTML templates.

`detail.html`:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %} {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type='radio' name='choice' id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}">
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br>{% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" value="vote"> </form>
```

`index.html`:

```
{%ls if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul> {% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p> {% endif %}
```

`results.html`:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul> {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ achoice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li> {% endfor %} </ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

Comment: "TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 1: 'ls'"—please show us your template.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I pasted the lines in the template/base.py.

Comment: That's not the right file. Please show us _your template_. The HTML file.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience... I pasted the code in my 3 HTML files in the template directory

Comment: index.html has `{%ls if ....`, what's that

Comment: Oh I literary feel so dumb... So much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your error message points to an error in your template:

```
TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 1: 'ls'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Looking at your `index.html` template, we see

```
{%ls if latest_question_list %}
```

`ls` is not a valid template tag. Remove it:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
```